# How can I update and delete nested items in JSON?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

How can I add, update and delete testDrives items from the .json file in this format using angular HttpClient requests:

```
{
    "cars": ["BMW", "Audi"],
    "testDrives": [
        {
            "start": "2020-06-03T11:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-06-03T12:00:00.000Z",
            "name": "BMW",
        },
        {
            "start": "2020-06-03T14:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-06-03T15:30:00.000Z",
            "name": "Audi",
        }
     ]
}
```

I have tries with headers, slashes and ids but it does not seem to work:

```
this.http
      .get(this.file+'testDrives[0]').subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: you can't update file by using angular, you can request .json file by HTTP get method and store data in a variable and manipulate data stored in a variable. To update file you need some server-side solution, you can create a rest API implement CRUD operations

Comment: Ок If the json is on a server, how would I update the nested file?